# Declare url variable in Uri.parse Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass three values to another activity and in the second activity i want to declare the intent different urls string into `Uri.parse` function but it gives me error saying `Value getLink must be initialized`

I got simple code when on button click it counts the clicks and passes value from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity`

MainActivity

```
generate_btn.setOnClickListener{
    btnClicks++
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
        if (btnClicks == 1) {
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks1", "1")
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 2) {
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks2", "2")
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 3) {
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks3", "3")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
val getLink: String
val btn = intent


val genBtn1 = intent.extras!!.getString("generate_btn_clicks1")
// tried with getStringExtra too but doesn't work
val genBtn2 = btn.getStringExtra("generate_btn_clicks2")
val genBtn3 = btn.getStringExtra("generate_btn_clicks3")

if (genBtn1 == "1") {
    getLink = "https://google.com/"
} else if(genBtn2 == "2") {
    getLink = "https://facebook.com/"
} else if(genBtn3 == "3") {
   getLink = "https://pinterest.com/"
}

val links = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getLink))
```

So its just simple count variable and passing data to Uri.parse but seems i cannot add Strings there? Whats is the problem i don't understand?

Comment: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks1", "1")` Change to: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", "1")`

Comment: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks2", "2")`Change to: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", "2")`

Comment: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks3", "3")` Change to: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", "3")`

Comment: `val genBtn = intent.extras!!.getString("generate_btn_clicks")`

Comment: `if (genBtn == "1") {} else if (genBtn == "2"){} else if (genBtn == "3"){}`

Comment: Still too cumbersome. one statement would do: `intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", btnClicks)`

Comment: `I want to pass three values to another activity`. No. Not at all. You just want to pass one value every time.

Comment: @blackapps yup you are right i want to pass one value at time. Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: `Value getLink must be initialized`. Yes. Now for instance if genBtn==0 or gnButton==4 then genLink has no value;/. And so there is nothing to parse then. So give it a start value; Or yet better do not parse then.

Comment: What should i use instead of `Uri.parse` to open an URL in a browser? BTW the starting value fixed my problem :)

Comment: Who said  you had to use something instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are making your code more complex than it is. It is a good practice to make it simpler but effective.
Rather than having your code like this:

```
if (btnClicks == 1) { 
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks1", "1")
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 2) {
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks2", "2")
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 3) {
            intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks3", "3")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

then have it:

```
intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", btnClicks)
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in your second activity:

```
val genBtn = btn.getIntExtra("generate_btn_clicks")

if (genBtn == 1) {
    getLink = "https://google.com/"
} else if(genBtn == 2) {
    getLink = "https://facebook.com/"
} else if(genBtn == 3) {
   getLink = "https://pinterest.com/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tidy up but this does not fixes my problem. As i said, on the last line in the example above, i get an error `Value getLink must be initialized`. I dont get it why it shows me that error when the `getLink` variable is initialized. Also your answer is with integer value and in `Uri.parse` function it needs to be given an String.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed thanks to @Tyrone and @blackapps
Now is more tidier and it works!

Here is the working complete code

MainActivity

```
generate_btn.setOnClickListener{
    btnClicks++
    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, SecondActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("generate_btn_clicks", btnClicks)

        if (btnClicks == 1) {
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 2) {
            startActivity(intent)
        } else if (btnClicks == 3) {
            startActivity(intent)
            btnClicks = 0
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity

```
val genBtn = intent.extras!!.getInt("generate_btn_clicks")
var getLink : String = ""

if (genBtn == 1) {
    getLink = "https://google.com"
} else if (genBtn == 2) {
    getLink = "https://facebook.com"
} else if (genBtn == 3) {
    getLink = "https://pinterest.com"
}

val intent_pic = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getLink))
```

Comment: No this does not fix all. You should add a last `else`. `else return;` Because what sense would it make to open an intent where getLink =="" ? I suggested that before. Display a nice Toast() if the value is unexpected.

Comment: There it is now its complete :) No need of other else or some messages i only need to return a value of `0` at the end